# Junit Test for an Object Save and Read Method

Tags: java, junit

I need help on the best way to Unit test an Object's Save and Read Method. This is simple Object, here is the constructor:

```
public Bill(String bname, Double bamount, Date bdate, String bfrequency){
    this.billName = bname;
    this.billAmount = bamount;
    this.billDueDate = bdate;
    this.frequency = bfrequency;

}
```

I implemented an Interface that will defines a read and save method like so

```
public interface IBill {
    public void save(Bill bill) throws IOException;
    public Bill read() throws IOException;
```

And bear with me, this is the concrete implementation of the above interface

```
public class BillSvcImpl implements IBill {

    @Override
    public void save(Bill bill) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oOut = null;

        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream("firstbill.ser");           
            oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);
            oOut.writeObject(bill);   //serializing Bill object

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            try{
                oOut.flush();
                oOut.close();
                fOut.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe){
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public Bill read() {

        Bill retrievedBill = null;
        FileInputStream fIn = null;
        ObjectInputStream oIn = null;

        try{
            fIn = new FileInputStream("firstbill.ser");         
            oIn = new ObjectInputStream(fIn);           
            retrievedBill = (Bill)oIn.readObject();

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf){
                    cnf.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            try{
                oIn.close();
                fIn.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return retrievedBill;
    }

    }
```

And finally here the test that I wanted to use to test this method and it fails

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    factory = new Factory();

}
@test
public void testSaveBill(){
    IBill bill = factory.getBillInfo();
    Bill nanny = new Bill("Nanny",128d,new Date(6/28/2013),"Montly");
    try {
        bill.save(nanny);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 @test
 public void testReadBill(){
     IBill rbill = factory.getBillInfo();
     try {
        rbill.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
```

}

I know my test is not right, so please help me re-write my test. The error message is `Java.lang.Exception: No runnable method`

Comment: The test probably doesn't even compile, because the annotation, like all the classes in Java, is spelt `@Test`, and not `@test`. Also, don't catch exceptions in the test methods. If you have an exception, you want your test to fail, not to succeed. The write and read methods should also throw exception rather than catching them. You don't want your program to continue as if nothing bad happened when an exception is thrown while writing or reading the bill. And streams should be closed whatever happened, in a finally block.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I should have mentioned that this is my first real foray into Java. Anyway, I applied your feedback( changed \@test to \@Test, removed try/catch from the read/write methods and the Test ran successfully. Thanks again for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

If you use JUnit 4.x then you need to mark your method with `@Test` annotation (case matters) for 3.x Test class must `extends TestCase` in order to make your test works.

If you design Unit test you don't have to actually serialize your object and then deserialize it. I would move `FileInputStream fIn`and `ObjectInputStream oIn` to class level attributes with `get/set` methods and Mock them in test (There are few good Mock Framework implementations [1](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [2](http://easymock.org/))